# What was her sentence suggestion?

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

I'm a judge, and I'm currently judging a littering case. I was going to go with the usual sentence of a public hanging, but when I texted my friend she gave me a much better idea

The problem is that I've forgotten it: I was sidetracked by the revelation that the litterer is actually a butterfly (or at least some sort of flying bug). And I can't text back because my friend has just blocked me

Could you remind me what that sentence idea could have been?

Hint:

> The sentence was a real punishment at some point

Answer (score 0):

The question suggests the idea of

> **litterbug**

So I propose that the sentence was

> You will be cocooned until you metamorphose.

Comment: Not quite. I've added a hint to the question